# Not able to access deployed web application other than on local computer

Tags: java, tomcat, networking

I am trying to deploy a web application with a url say

http://10.x.x.x:8080/test using apache tomcat. This works from local computer. 
The problem is the address 10.x.x.x is my ipv4 address and when i try to hit this from other computers its not accessible.
Using noip / what is my ipaddress.com I also see that the public ip is different other than ipv4 address.
Even if i try http://1.x.x.x:8080/test it dosent work. Moreover i found that when i do a ping 1.x.x.x from command prompt it times out without success.

I am using an wifi dongle.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a wifi dongle. With a router yes. On the router you need to create a NAT Setting also called Virtual Server. You need to make a NAT setting or a Virtual Server entry. This varies depending on the make of the router. Add an entry that forwards requests made at port 8080 to internal ipv4 address hosting the tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

10.x.x.x is an IPv4 private IP address.  It is not addressable outside of your "local network". The chances are that your computer doesn't have a public IP address at all.

Your computer is probably talking to the outside world via a NAT server.  By default, that only works for out-going connections. Depending on how your networking is set up, it might be possible to configure the NAT server to map a port on its public IP address through to port 8080 on your computer.

But this is not a programming issue.  The question doesn't belong here.